# How do I refine this query to return individual product id's with their quantity summed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

this is in reality a follow up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232093/how-does-one-structure-queries-to-amalgamate-master-detail-records-over-a-given) question.

The following query produces the results shown.  How do I refine it so that it returns single rows for each product Id with their respective quantities summed.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ld.ProductId, ld.Quantity,ld.UnitPrice ,
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(lh1.LandingId AS VARCHAR) FROM dbo.LandingHeaders lh1 WHERE (lh1.LandingDate  BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20171107') AND (lh1.VesselOwnerId = 42
  ) FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS LandingIds

  FROM LandingHeaders lh 
  JOIN LandingDetails ld ON lh.LandingId = ld.LandingId
  WHERE (lh.LandingDate BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20171107') AND (lh.VesselOwnerId = 42)
  GROUP BY ld.ProductId,lh.LandingId,ld.Quantity,ld.UnitPrice
```

[image]

Comment: wrap your query as a subquery,  in the main query do the sums and group by

Comment: Change GROUP BY clause accoordingly  and add the aggregation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `SUM` the quantity column, and not `GROUP BY` it. Also, please always give the explicit length when using `varchar`:

```
SELECT  ld.ProductId, 
        SUM(ld.Quantity) Quantity,
        ld.UnitPrice,
        STUFF(( SELECT ',' + CAST(lh1.LandingId AS VARCHAR(20)) 
                FROM dbo.LandingHeaders lh1 
                WHERE lh1.LandingDate  BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20171107' 
                AND lh1.VesselOwnerId = 42 FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS LandingIds
FROM LandingHeaders lh 
INNER JOIN LandingDetails ld 
    ON lh.LandingId = ld.LandingId
WHERE lh.LandingDate BETWEEN '20171101' AND '20171107' 
AND lh.VesselOwnerId = 42
GROUP BY ld.ProductId,
         ld.UnitPrice
;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example.  I take your point about the undefined varchar, it's not something I'd normally leave undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT productId, SUM(quantity), MAX(unitprice)
FROM
(<your query>) as t
GROUP BY productId
```